# Javascript - Help Displaying Calculations in Calorie Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

I am a first year programming student, so I am sorry if this questions seems a little nooby.
I have created a Calorie Calculator and am having an issue displaying the end result (how many calories they need to take in/let out to reach their desired weight). Also, I apologize for the inline CSS, please ignore it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Added HTML,JS snippet (sorry about that!). I am still having issues with getting the end result to display.

```js
//var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    function getCalc() {
      var weight = document.querySelector('.weight');
//var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
    var height = document.querySelector('.height');
//var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var age = document.querySelector('.weight');
//var goalweight = document.getElementById("goalweight").value;
    var goalweight = document.querySelector('.goalweight');
//var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
    var gender = document.querySelector('.gender');
//var activity = document.getElementById("activity").value;
    var activity = document.querySelector('.activity');
    var BMR = " ";
    var BMRGoal = " ";
    var dailyCalories = " ";
    var goalCalories = " ";
if (gender == "male") {
BMR = 66.47+(6.24*weight)+(12.7*height)-(6.755*age);
BMRGoal = 66.47+(6.24*goalweight)+(12.7*height)-(6.755*age);
} else {
BMR = 655.1+(4.35*weight)+(4.7*height)-(4.7*age);
BMRGoal = 66.47+(6.24*goalweight)+(12.7*height)-(6.755*age);
}
if (activity == "none") {
 dailyCalories = BMR*1.2;
 goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
} else if (activity == 'light') {
 dailyCalories = BMR*1.375;
 goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
} else if (activity == 'moderate') {
 dailyCalories = BMR*1.55;
 goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
} else if (activity == 'heavy') {
 dailyCalories = BMR*1.725;
 goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
} else if (activity == 'xheavy') {
 dailyCalories = BMR*1.9;
 goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
}
document.getElementByClassName('requireddailycals').innerHTML = 'Your current daily calorie intake is ' + dailyCalories + '. In order to reach your desired weight goal, you will need to increase your caloric intake to ' + goalCalories + '.';
document.getElementById("requireddailycals").value = dailyCalories(goalCalories);
 
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Nutrition Calculator</title>
<style>
body {
background-color:rgba(102,143,74, 0.3);
}
a {
text-decoration:none;
}
.calcalc_box {
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
top:35vh;
transform:translateY(-35%);
left:50vw;
transform:translateX(-50%);
border:0.2vw solid #a6b727;
text-align:center;
padding:5vw;
font-family:Arial;
box-shadow:0.5vw 0.5vh 0 #a6b727;
}
.calcalc_box > h1 {
font-family:Lucida Console;
color:#316886;
font-size:3vw;
}
.calcalc_box > h2 {
color:#a6b727;
margin:5vh 0 5vh 0;
}
.calcalc_logo {
margin:auto;
}
.calcalc_button {
background-color:#a6b727;
color:black;
padding:0.8vw;
font-size:1.3vw;
font-weight:bold;
border:0.2vw solid #a6b727;
margin:0.5vw;
display:inline-block;
border-radius:0.3vw;
}
.calcalc_button:hover {
background-color:rgba(102,143,74, 0.3);
}
label {
display:inline;
color:#a6b727;
font-weight:bold;
}
.the_calculator {
border:0.2vw solid #a6b727;
text-align:left;
padding:0.5vw;
}
.calculator_section {
display:inline-block;
margin:1vw 0 1vw 0;
width:100%;
}
.calculator_section > label {
font-weight:bold;
padding:0.5vw;
}
.calculator_input {
padding:0.5vw;
margin-bottom:2vw;
}
.calcalc_back {
color:#a6b727;
font-weight:bold;
padding:2vw;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="calcalc_box">
<img src="calcalc.png" width="250" height="250" />
<h1>Cal-Calc</h1>
<h2>Nutrition Calculator</h2>
<form class="the_calculator">
<div class="calculator_section">
<label for="gender">Gender</label>
Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="gender">
Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="gender">
</div>
<label for="age">Age : </label><input type="number" name="age" class="calculator_input" id="age"><br>
<label for="height">Height (in inches) : </label><input type="number" name="height" class="calculator_input" id="height"><br>
<label for="weight">Weight (in pounds) : </label><input type="number" name="weight" class="calculator_input" id="weight"><br>
<label for="goalweight">Goal Weight : </label><input type="number" name="weight" class="calculator_input" id="goalweight"><br>
<label for="activity">Activity Level</label>
              Little to no exercise <input type="radio" name="activity" value="none" id="activity">
Light Exercise (walks, runs) <input type="radio" name="activity" value="light" id="activity">
Moderate Exercise (sports) <input type="radio" name="activity" value="moderate" id="activity">
 Heavy Exercise (daily consistent routine) <input type="radio" name="activity" value="heavy" id="activity">
Extra Heavy Exercise (twice daily consistent routine) <input type="radio" name="activity" value="xheavy" id="activity">
<br><br>
<button class="calcalc_button" onClick="getCalc()" style="margin-left:13vw;" >Calculate
        </button>
        <span class= "requireddailycals"></span>
</form>
<a href="index.html"><span class="calcalc_back"><br><br><br>click here to go back</span></a>
</div>
<script src="./project.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add your JS to the snippet as well

Comment: Added :) @knosmos

Comment: you haven't taken into account knosmos' remark on my answer, you need to change your last javascript line

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML you have:

```
<span class= "requireddailycals"/span>
```

Try instead:

```
<span class= "requireddailycals"></span>
```

Then change the JS this way:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("requireddailycals")[0].innerHTML = 'Your current daily calorie intake is ' + dailyCalories + '. In order to reach your desired weight goal, you will need to increase your caloric intake to ' + goalCalories + '.';
```

or better, get the element by id

NB: try to use the JS/HTML/CSS snipped to allow use to run your code more easily.

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName` doesn't exist. Use `document.getElementsByClassName("requireddailycals")[0]`. Actually in this case, you should use `id` instead of `class`.

Comment: Gotcha. Updated the code snippet. I'll test out using an ID too

Answer (score 1):

I used an `eventListener()` with `preventDefault()`. You can also add a `type="button"` to your calculate button if you continue to use an inline HTML event attributes but that is not recommended.

I also changed your `querySelector` because you were attempting to select an `element` by `id`, and you were using a `class` as a `selector`.

You also had a minor typo, which did not break your code.
This will solve your problem:

```js
 document.querySelector('.calcalc_button').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
        var height = document.getElementById("height").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var goalweight = document.getElementById("goalweight").value;
        var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
        var activity = document.getElementById("activity").value;
            var BMR = " ";
            var BMRGoal = " ";
            var dailyCalories = " ";
            var goalCalories = " ";
            if (gender == "male") {
            BMR = 66.47+(6.24*weight)+(12.7*height)-(6.755*age);
            BMRGoal = 66.47+(6.24*goalweight)+(12.7*height)-(6.755*age);
            } else {
            BMR = 655.1+(4.35*weight)+(4.7*height)-(4.7*age);
            BMRGoal = 66.47+(6.24*goalweight)+(12.7*height)-(6.755*age);
            }
            if (activity == "none") {
             dailyCalories = BMR*1.2;
             goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
            } else if (activity == 'light') {
             dailyCalories = BMR*1.375;
             goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
            } else if (activity == 'moderate') {
             dailyCalories = BMR*1.55;
             goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
            } else if (activity == 'heavy') {
             dailyCalories = BMR*1.725;
             goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
            } else if (activity == 'xheavy') {
             dailyCalories = BMR*1.9;
             goalCalories = BMRGoal*1.2;
            }
            document.querySelector('.requireddailycals').innerHTML = 'Your current daily calorie intake is ' + dailyCalories + '. In order to reach your desired weight goal, you will need to increase your caloric intake to ' + goalCalories + '.';
            //document.getElementById("requireddailycals").value = dailyCalories(goalCalories);
         })

        //var weight = document.getElementById("weight").value;
        function getCalc() {
            preventDefault();
            console.log("asd");
 
    }
```

```css
body {
background-color:rgba(102,143,74, 0.3);
}
a {
text-decoration:none;
}
.calcalc_box {
position:absolute;
margin:auto;
top:35vh;
transform:translateY(-35%);
left:50vw;
transform:translateX(-50%);
border:0.2vw solid #a6b727;
text-align:center;
padding:5vw;
font-family:Arial;
box-shadow:0.5vw 0.5vh 0 #a6b727;
}
.calcalc_box > h1 {
font-family:Lucida Console;
color:#316886;
font-size:3vw;
}
.calcalc_box > h2 {
color:#a6b727;
margin:5vh 0 5vh 0;
}
.calcalc_logo {
margin:auto;
}
.calcalc_button {
background-color:#a6b727;
color:black;
padding:0.8vw;
font-size:1.3vw;
font-weight:bold;
border:0.2vw solid #a6b727;
margin:0.5vw;
display:inline-block;
border-radius:0.3vw;
}
.calcalc_button:hover {
background-color:rgba(102,143,74, 0.3);
}
label {
display:inline;
color:#a6b727;
font-weight:bold;
}
.the_calculator {
border:0.2vw solid #a6b727;
text-align:left;
padding:0.5vw;
}
.calculator_section {
display:inline-block;
margin:1vw 0 1vw 0;
width:100%;
}
.calculator_section > label {
font-weight:bold;
padding:0.5vw;
}
.calculator_input {
padding:0.5vw;
margin-bottom:2vw;
}
.calcalc_back {
color:#a6b727;
font-weight:bold;
padding:2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="calcalc_box">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" width="250" height="250" />
<h1>Cal-Calc</h1>
<h2>Nutrition Calculator</h2>
<form class="the_calculator">
<div class="calculator_section">
<label for="gender">Gender</label>
Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="gender">
Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="gender">
</div>
<label for="age">Age : </label><input type="number" name="age" class="calculator_input" id="age"><br>
<label for="height">Height (in inches) : </label><input type="number" name="height" class="calculator_input" id="height"><br>
<label for="weight">Weight (in pounds) : </label><input type="number" name="weight" class="calculator_input" id="weight"><br>
<label for="goalweight">Goal Weight : </label><input type="number" name="weight" class="calculator_input" id="goalweight"><br>
<label for="activity">Activity Level</label>
              Little to no exercise <input type="radio" name="activity" value="none" id="activity">
Light Exercise (walks, runs) <input type="radio" name="activity" value="light" id="activity">
Moderate Exercise (sports) <input type="radio" name="activity" value="moderate" id="activity">
 Heavy Exercise (daily consistent routine) <input type="radio" name="activity" value="heavy" id="activity">
Extra Heavy Exercise (twice daily consistent routine) <input type="radio" name="activity" value="xheavy" id="activity">
<br><br>
<button class="calcalc_button" style="margin-left:13vw;" >Calculate</button>
        <span class= "requireddailycals"></span>
</form>
<a href="index.html"><span class="calcalc_back"><br><br><br>click here to go back</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Having some description of what you changed would be nice. Also, how did you answer a closed question?

Comment: Nick of time, I suppose. I'm editing the answer right now.